# Change to .length with toUpperCase?

Tags: javascript, string, substring, string-length

I found this line in a jQuery plugin:

```
node.data.substr(0, pos).toUpperCase().length - node.data.substr(0, pos).length
```

As fas as I can tell, this should always give zero, as the only difference is the `toUpperCase()`, which shouldn't change the length of a string.

What is happening here?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the jQuery plugin source and pinpoint the line for us? Maybe it's something before it.

Comment: You want to say that the length of the two calls is different? The line looks totally ok for me .... maybe something other changes the string ... some more code would be nice.

Comment: Here it is http://johannburkard.de/resources/Johann/jquery.highlight-5.js

Comment: Just a note from [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_touppercase.asp) that may help. The toUpperCase() method does not change the original string.

Comment: Line 22 - basically, they are checking for a match by using indexOf and then looking for a return higher or equal 0. Before that, the line in question does... something?

Answer (score 4):

Some Unicode characters, especially with ligatures, are problematic when converting to uppercase, since they have no corresponding character for that and instead might be converted to 2 characters.

Code example:

```js
var lowerChar = '\uFB00';
console.log("lowercase: ", lowerChar, "length: ", lowerChar.length);
var upperChar = lowerChar.toUpperCase();
console.log("uppercase: ", upperChar, "length: ", upperChar.length);
```

Comment: So you think this is a check for special characters? In that case, it doesn't do a very good job of it - it only changes the behavior of the program if the difference is more than the index of the match - which is obviously brittle and hard to debug.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the answer or the intent :/

Comment: @Andreas I edited in a code example, see for yourself

Comment: I see - but checking for this in the manner above seems to only introduce bugs.

Can  you imagine a case where this actually helps? I can't think of a use case

Answer (score 2):

Believe it or not, **some characters turn into multiple characters when you convert them into uppercase.**

For example, there is a set of special characters that look like two letters. One of these is [Latin Small Ligature FI](https://graphemica.com/%EF%AC%81), which exists because of a typographic thing called “ligatures”. There are special characters for “FF”, “FL”, “FFI”, and “FFL” as well. These would turn into 2 or 3 characters from `.toUppercase()`.

Another example is the German letter [eszett](https://graphemica.com/%C3%9F). While [an uppercase version exists](https://graphemica.com/%E1%BA%9E) and was officially approved by the Council for German Orthography in 2017, all browsers still convert the single letter "ß" into the two letters "SS".

Test program:

```
function countUpperDiff(input) {
  console.log((input.toUpperCase().length - input.length) + ": " + input + " → " + input.toUpperCase());
}

console.log("This program prints how many characters longer the uppercase version becomes, followed by a before-and-after view.");

console.log("Some typographic ligatures exist in lowercase, but not uppercase.")
countUpperDiff("fix");
countUpperDiff("ﬁx");
countUpperDiff("fly");
countUpperDiff("ﬂy");
countUpperDiff("off");
countUpperDiff("oﬀ");
countUpperDiff("affix");
countUpperDiff("aﬃx");
countUpperDiff("raffle");
countUpperDiff("raﬄe");

console.log("\nThe German letter ß is NOT converted into the capital letter ẞ, but into SS. This all-caps conversion is a problem for some words:")
countUpperDiff("in massen");
countUpperDiff("in maßen");
console.log("The first one means \"in massive amounts\", while the second one means \"in moderate amounts\".")
```

Output:

```
This program prints how many characters longer the uppercase version becomes, followed by a before-and-after view.
Some typographic ligatures exist in lowercase, but not uppercase.
0: fix → FIX
1: ﬁx → FIX
0: fly → FLY
1: ﬂy → FLY
0: off → OFF
1: oﬀ → OFF
0: affix → AFFIX
2: aﬃx → AFFIX
0: raffle → RAFFLE
2: raﬄe → RAFFLE

The German letter ß is NOT converted into the capital letter ẞ, but into SS. This is a problem for some words:
0: in massen → IN MASSEN
1: in maßen → IN MASSEN
The first one means "in massive amounts", while the second one means "in moderate amounts".
```