# Can `toLowerCase` change a JavaScript string's length?

Tags: javascript, string, unicode, internationalization, string-length

Is it ever possible that `string.length !== string.toLowerCase().length`?

I know it is possible for `toUpperCase`, given the answers at [Change to .length with toUpperCase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49895784/change-to-length-with-touppercase), but I don't know whether it's possible for `toLowerCase`.

Comment: I mean, acccording to your link, if certain characters are defined by different amount of characters depending on their size, then `yes`. In that case, the same methodology could be applied and shown that .toLowerCase() wouldve given off a 1 in length instead of 2 as it was first defined (uppercase state).

Comment: @DragonInTraining That isn't necessarily the case. The examples given in the answers to the linked question do not cause the string to revert to its original length when `toLowerCase` is called after `toUpperCase`. See for yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, not all case mappings are one to one, they can also be one-to-many as you've seen when going from lowercase to uppercase, the same can apply when going from uppercase to lowercase. This can be seen with the *LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH DOT ABOVE*, 0x0130 character - ie: `İ`:

```js
const char = "\u0130"; // İ
const charLower = char.toLowerCase();
console.log(char, char.length); // İ 1
console.log(charLower, charLower.length); // i̇ 2
console.log(char.length !== charLower.length); // true
```

There is also a note in the ECMAScript specification that highlights this behavior at section [22.1.3.26](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-string.prototype.tolowercase) aswell:

> The case mapping of some code points may produce multiple code points.
> In this case the result String may not be the same length as the
> source String

A list of special case mappings (ie: case mappings that aren't necessarily one-to-one) can be found in the [Unicode Character Database](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/SpecialCasing.txt) (UCD). As listed, the length of some characters only grows when under certain conditions, some of these depend on specific contexts and locales:

```js
// From the UCD for SpecialCasings, another example can be found: 
// 012E; 012F 0307; 012E; 012E; lt More_Above; # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH OGONEK
// The above means '012E' maps to the lower case of '012F 0307' if:
// - the locale is Lithuanian (lt)
// - the suffix contains a character of combining class 230 (Above)
// \u0300 is a character with such a combining class value (list found here: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/combining/230)

const grapheme = '\u012E\u0300'; // Į̀ (Į +  ̀ )
console.log(grapheme, grapheme.length); // Į̀ 2

const lowerStd = grapheme.toLowerCase();
console.log(lowerStd, lowerStd.length); // į̀ 2 (still fine)

const lowerLocale = grapheme.toLocaleLowerCase('lt');
console.log(lowerLocale, lowerLocale.length); // į̇̀ 3 (now 3 when using lt as the locale)
```